# Can anyone explain step by step process (recursion) for below example :

Tags: javascript, recursion

I referred this link ([What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion?rq=1)) but i can't get the answer by applying those steps ,can anyone explain please?

```
let sum = 5;
function sumTo(n) {

    if(n==1) return n;
    else {
        return sum + sumTo(n-1);
    }
}
let ss = sumTo(5);
```

Comment: Its explained well in accepted answer

Comment: Such title is really useless.

Comment: This is not a duplicate,look briefly the question first or run above question and analysis briefly @satpal

Comment: look *closely* at this line in your code: `return sum + sumTo(n-1);`, and compare it to the example in the duplicate question:  `return x + recsum(x-1);`.  In your code, you are trying to return the sum of the outside value every time, whereas in the other example, the sum is on the passed in value, making it cumulative.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestion, finally i understood and came to answer my self

Comment: thank you claies. Here the answer for above question :          
    5 + sum(4);
    5 + 5 + sum(3);
    5 + 5 + 5 + sum(2);
    5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + sum(1);
    5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 1;